# Saving data to binary file, which method is correct?

Tags: c++, file

I want to save a string to a **binary** file, which is correct?

```
std::ofstream outfile(filename, std::ios_base::binary);


string str="some text";
for (const char &i : str) {
            outfile.write((const char *) &i, sizeof(char));
        }
```

or:

```
outfile.write((const char *) &str, str.length()*sizeof(char));
```

**Note: I don't want to save the null terminator at the end of the string.**

Comment: Please let me know if more details are needed

Comment: Both seem correct, what issues are you facing?

Comment: @ÖöTiib won't the second save the null terminator too?

Comment: No, second does not save null terminator. Otherwise when opening check that it is good and when writing check that it succeeded. Also more paranoid close explicitly and check that it succeeded too. There may be access errors or media may get full and the like.

Comment: I didn't understand "Also more paranoid close explicitly and check that it succeeded too"

Comment: I read there is no need to close file after opening it if all of this is done in a function

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/close/ if it fails then you likely have broken file and failbit is set. If you ignore it then your program can't tell that to user.

Comment: The second seems dodgy to me. Why not use `str.data()` or `str.c_str()`? Are you writing the length somewhere so you will be able to read this back?

Comment: The second will not write the characters of the string, and has undefined behaviour if the string length is greater than `sizeof(std::string)`.  You will not be able to read it back. Do `outfile.write(str.data(), str.length());`

Comment: BTW, `sizeof(char)` is 1, by definition.

Comment: @molbdnilo and how should I read them back?

Comment: This didn't work (it worked on the first method only)         infile.read((char *) &tmp, sizeofdata*sizeof(char));

Comment: @daniel If you're referring to my suggested replacement, it does exactly the same thing as your first piece of code, but more conventionally and with less code.

Comment: I mean how to read the data

Comment: may you kindly respond I did the changes you suggested to the save function but now the load function doesn't work, how should I load data

Comment: @molbdnilo any help?

Comment: The general way to serialize a string is to write the length of the string followed by the data of the string. To read it back you read the length and then read the data into a buffer of that length.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the correct method is to write the string's length first, followed by the string's content:

```
const std::string example_text = "Redwood trees are very tall.";
const unsigned int length = example_text.length();
outfile.write((char *) &length, sizeof(length));
outfile.write(example_text.data(), length);
```

This allows for using block reading:

```
unsigned int length;
outfile.read((char *) &length, sizeof(length));
std::string text;
text.reserve(length);
outfile.read(text.data(), length);
```